# Free software license for libraries

Tags: licensing

I am developing a library and I want to use a Free software license. There are thousands of licenses, but I do not understand their differences. I need help to choose a license.

I want a license that:

- Allows to statically or dynamically link unmodified library to any Free or proprietary project.
- Allows to freely distribute unmodified library.
- Allows to modify and to distribute with modification if the modified library is open source and keeps this license.

<s>If LGPL allowed dynamic link to proprietary software, I would choose it.</s> (My mistake)

If LGPL allowed static link to proprietary software, I would choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LGPL 2.1 allows static linking, you can also add it as an exception to any other version, for example:

> As a special exception, the copyright
>   holders of this library give you
>   permission to link this library with
>   independent modules to produce an
>   executable, regardless of the license
>   terms of these independent modules,
>   and to copy and distribute the
>   resulting executable under terms of
>   your choice, provided that you also
>   meet, for each linked independent
>   module, the terms and conditions of
>   the license of that module. An
>   independent module is a module which
>   is not derived from or based on this
>   library. If you modify this library,
>   you must extend this exception to your
>   version of the library.

Answer (score 1):

> If LGPL allowed dynamic link to proprietary software, I would choose it.

The LGPL does allow dynamic linking thats the point, static linking is a little trickier.
There are LGPL+extended licenses that allow static linking (eg wxWidgets)

If you want to allow your lib to be linked with proprietry software and you don't want to force anbody to release their changes then a BSD license is probably what you want.

Generally allowing people to do things with your code isn't the problem, it's forcing them to do something like release their changes!

Comment: I want to allow to use it for any purpose, but I want to force them to release their changes.

Comment: Then i would say LGPL+static linking exemption eg. http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm